# How to Save records in Database using Grails Services

Tags: grails

I have a domain class called Classified. This class has a relation ship(hasMany) with Media class:

```
class Classified{
static hasMany = [ adResponses: AdResponse,mediafiles:Media ] 
}

class Media{
     byte[] mediafile
}
```

When I save the Classified object from Classified Controller, I am able to save the Parent as well as Child object using below code:

```
def save(){
   def med = new Media(mediafile: params.mediafile, contentType:uploadedFile?.contentType)
   classifiedInstance.addToMediafiles(med)
   classifiedInstance.save flush:true
}
```

Below is my ClassifiedService to save the data.

```
    @Transactional
    class ClassifiedService {


        def addAd(Classified classifiedInstance)
   {

    classifiedInstance.save flush:true
   }
 }
```

In the above "addAd" method I am passing object of Classified instance.

Save method of ClassifiedController:

```
def save(){
   def med = new Media(mediafile: params.mediafile,  contentType:uploadedFile?.contentType)
   classifiedInstance.addToMediafiles(med)
   classifiedService.addAd(classifiedInstance)
}
```

Nothing happends when I try to save. On Console I dont see any error.

Please let me know why I am not able to save the data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you see expected results if you change your method in your service to be void addAd(Classified classifiedInstance) instead of def?

Comment: also be sure to check the return value of save and in case it is ``false`` check for ``.errors`` on the domain object

Comment: I removed return type and it worked. How in this Grails worlds. I am not understanding it. Someone please explain?

Comment: It is driving me crazy, I tried many patterns... made it as void, then caught the return value in object and in all ways it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the following :

1. You have imported the domain class on top of your service definition
2. change this save method to failOn save to see more errors

   def med = new Media(mediafile: params.mediafile, contentType:uploadedFile?.contentType)
      classifiedInstance.addToMediafiles(med)
      classifiedInstance.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
3. Please , some times restarting the STS could help , since u are not seeing any error , so clean it and make refresh dependency if no error close and reopen.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you have to use withTransaction inside services. You don't. That's not a requirement. Care to explain why you think you have to?

Comment: joshua have u seen this specifed on the service defintion  @Transactional

Comment: Yes, I had seen that and that makes no requirement to use withTransaction. In fact that is wrapping the contents of each method in a transactional block (using an AST transformation in later versions of Grails and a Transactional proxy in earlier versions). I still fail to understand why you think using withTransaction is required. There are cases where withTransaction make sense (multiple transactions within a single method), but it's not required.

Comment: Take a look at the 2.3.x documentation. It talks about programatic transactions using withTransaction and declarative transactions. They aren't the same: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html

Comment: ye joshau ..the probelm may be not importing the domain itself ... i have tired to look some other sources and they save without transactioanlity...updating the answerr

Answer (score 0):

I followed Joshua. Restarted my machine, and started GGTS and its working great.